# How to float a section in bootstrap navigation bar to the right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a navigation bar using [bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com)

I've got this [sample demo here](http://www.bootply.com/SiddharthP/pmgBuCahrv) in which I've not created the menu items using ul and li tags because I wanted to use the font icons and group them by `btn-group` class. The second reason of not using ul tags for nav items is when the navbar is in mobile view state, I don't want the nav items to stack instead it should only have one row with all these icons in it.

I don't want to change the design of this navigation bar but I want to move the section from text - "Log Details" and the icons right to it to the right. I've tried using `pull-right` and `navbar-right` but it doesn't help.

So, my question is how should I float the above section in bootstrap navigation bar to the right, such that it respects the right padding of the `.container` class as you can see the gap for the nav items on the left ?
below is the html markup of my navigation bar:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>
                <div class="btn-group navbar-left"> <a id="shell_navigation_go_back" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>

                    <a id="shell_navigation_go_to_home" href="#/home" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>

                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p id="shell_title_area" class="navbar-text">Title</p>
            <div class="">
                <p id="shell_update_log_area" class="navbar-text">Log Details</p>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for
                toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <div class="btn-group"> <a id="shell_navigation_display_hub_details" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a>

                        <a id="shell_navigation_refresh_view" href="#/refresh" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>

                            </a>
                    </div> <a id="shell_navigation_sort_and_filter" href="#/refresh" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></a>

                    <a id="shell_navigation_display_extra_options" href="#/refresh" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>

                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: http://www.bootply.com/HccIKNsQwO

Just remove the `div` containing your 'Log Details' and navbar, add `pull-right` class to your  `navbar-collapse` (with your button) and `navbar-text` with log details and switch their position in HTML.

Comment: I've already tried this but this isn't that I want to achieve. Log Details text needs to be out of collapse section as it should be visible even in the mobile state. And by adding float right, the whole section moves to the right but gets stick to the outer border.

Answer (score 0):

I've now achieved the design by changing my nav bar markup like below which can also be seen with the demo link in my question:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="btn-group navbar-left">
                            <a id="shell_navigation_go_back" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                            <a id="shell_navigation_go_to_home" href="#/home" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p id="shell_title_area" class="navbar-text">Title</p>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <p id="shell_update_log_area" class="navbar-text">Log Details</p>    
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a id="shell_navigation_display_hub_details" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a>
                                    <a id="shell_navigation_refresh_view" href="#/refresh" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a>
                                </div>
                                <a id="shell_navigation_sort_and_filter" href="#/refresh" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></a>
                                <a id="shell_navigation_display_extra_options" href="#/refresh" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```